# Removing the focused effect on all the elements

Tags: css, javafx-2

Currently I use this for the button:

```
.button:focused{
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

But is there any way to remove the effect on all the elements at the same time? Or do I have to add an `id` to all the elements that can be focused and put that line into the `id`?

Also seems that the '.' annotation only works with the button, tried with `.textfield` or `.scrollpane` yet they didn't seem to work, or have to write it in some other way?

If I wanted to generate that colored border (like the focused one) how should I do it? tried with:

```
#highlight{
    -fx-background-insets: 2;
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work (`-fx-background-color` fills everything with the color)

Comment: `*:focus {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}`

Comment: just tried it, doesn't work (in fact, the * does nothing...)

Comment: so using this way? `*:focus{
 -fx-background-insets: 0 !important;
}` doesn't work neither, or I have to add something anywhere else? (never used the !important before)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6c7yV/ if instead of `*:focus` I use `.button:focused` works (but only for the button)

Comment: Tried `*:focused`? I can't test your fiddle as it's supposed to be for HTML/CSS

Comment: yes, also tested focused, or is just that javafx css dont accept the '*' annotation? (i know that javafx css is quite restricted, but no idea on how much, also the documentation is quite poor)

Comment: Yeah the documentation is quite poor, I read through it and couldn't find anything saying this wasn't allowed :/

Comment: Try to add listener on focusOwner property of the scene, and when focus changes, move focus on some invisible node, using requestFocus() method.

Comment: ummm isn't this a bit annoying way to do it? since the scene i change it with `scene.setRoot(new ViewController())`, I'll have to create a new element in each view and a method setFocusListener on each of the controllers to add the listener, is there really no easier way?